# Wait for text to speech and music to complete before registering next onClick

Tags: java, android

I have several buttons that respond to an onClick. When the buttons are pressed, it triggers a text to speech that says the name of the button and some music that corresponds to the button. However, the app glitches because you can press a different button while the music and text to speech for one button are still running. Is there a way to wait for the text to speech and music to stop playing before allowing another click? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks a lot!!!

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

        Resources res = getResources();
        Button btn = (Button) view;
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.green_button:

                String greenString = res.getString(R.string.Green);
                tv.setText(greenString);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    tts.speak(greenString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } else {
                    tts.speak(greenString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                }
                MediaPlayer green = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.green);
                green.start();

                break;

            case R.id.red_button:

                String redString = res.getString(R.string.Red);
                tv.setText(redString);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    tts.speak(redString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } else {
                    tts.speak(redString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
                }
                MediaPlayer red = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.red);
                red.start();

                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must invoke tts.shutdown() in onClick() and then create the other tts object.

```
public void onClick(View view) { 
   tts.shutdown();
   tts = new TextToSpeech(context, listener)

   /* your code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put if statement that checks if tts object is playing , `tts.isSpeaking()` return boolean true if speaking.